# Get value of undefined Object property

Tags: javascript

If I have an object which looks like this:

```
Object{
    undefined : 20
}
```

What is the best way of getting the value of the undefined property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define an object like that, it is not using the keyword `undefined` as the key, rather it is a **string key**. So access it with quotes

```js
var test = {
    undefined : 20
};
console.log(test['undefined']);
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. I'll accept this as the correct answer in 11 minutes when I can.

Comment: also doing `object[undefined]` is same as `object["undefined"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var obj = {undefined : 20}
```

You can get

```
 obj.undefined
```

or

```
 obj['undefined']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `foo['undefined']`. It's the best way if you're not sure of the key